# I want to make django chat application

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, chat

**I want to make a django chat app but I searched hours and I couldn't find how , youtube tutorials use react and I don't know react js**

Pls give me a way to study on how to make it and where to get it

Done through official django docs but got errror with redis...

It would be kind if you also can tell me about the steps involved in making....

Comment: There's no such thing "django chat application". You can create your chat with python console, and then use django as your `GUI`. You must get creative instead of following tutorials `;)`

Comment: `django`/`flask`/`bottle`/`PHP` are for web pages which uses method `client-server` which means: `client (web browser)` sends `question/request` and `server (django)` send back `answer/response`. `Server` never send `requests` to `client` and `client` never send back `response`. Applications like `chat` need `JavaScript` with `ajax` or `websocket` to communicate in two directions - to send requets from server to client using `websocket` or simulate it using `ajax`. So you have to learn `JavaScript` for this.

Comment: yes but can i do with raw js, or do i need to learn react?